# Why python os is working only on default directory and how to change it?

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system, shutil

```
import os
import shutil

FileCount = 0
filelist = []
ext = str(input())

for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk('F:\\'):    
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith(ext):
            txtFileCount+=1;
            filelist.append(filename)
            print(os.path.abspath(filename))


print(txtFileCount)
print(filelist)
```

output:
The files are of 'G' directory while chosen directory is 'F'.

```
G:\Pillow\filecheckerProject\free_cam_8_7_0.msi
G:\Pillow\filecheckerProject\BlueJ-windows-421.msi
G:\Pillow\filecheckerProject\free_cam_8_7_0.msi
G:\Pillow\filecheckerProject\mysql-installer-web-community-8.0.17.0.msi
G:\Pillow\filecheckerProject\PowerToysSetup.msi
5
['free_cam_8_7_0.msi', 'BlueJ-windows-421.msi', 'free_cam_8_7_0.msi', 'mysql-installer-web-community-8.0.17.0.msi', 'PowerToysSetup.msi']
```

Comment: Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Please clarify your question and also as @БогданОпир said, format your code properly so it is easier to understand.

Comment: You're ignoring the `foldername` given to you from `os.walk`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `os.path.abspath(filename)`, you're passing just a filename, like `'free_cam_8_7_0.msi'`. The `abspath` function can't know what folder you're talking about with just that information.

But `os.walk` is giving you the folder; you're just not using it.

```
for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk('F:\\'):    
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith(ext):
            txtFileCount+=1;
            filelist.append(filename)
            filepath = os.path.join(foldername, filename) # join the folder name and the filename
            print(os.path.abspath(filepath))
```